# Using django channels for notificaitons

Tags: django, notifications, django-channels

I am working on a django project that allows two users chat together. Once you receive a new message, you get notification.  To do both tasks, I am using django channels and opening a websocket.  With my chat app working as intended, I moved on to work on the notifications part. However, that is where I face some problems.

I have a signals.py where whenever a notification gets created, I send it to the room for the user.

**signals.py**

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Notification)
def newNotification(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:

        channel_layer = get_channel_layer()
        room_name = "notif_room_for_user_"+str(instance.targetUser.id)

        async_to_sync( channel_layer.group_send)(
                   room_name, {"type": "user.gossip",
                   "event": instance.objectName,
                   "targetUser": instance.targetUser}
        )
```

**consumers.py**

```
class NoseyConsumer(AsyncJsonWebsocketConsumer):

async def connect(self):

    self.user = self.scope["user"]
    self.user_room_name = "notif_room_for_user_"+str(self.user.id) 

    await self.channel_layer.group_add(
            self.user_room_name,
            self.channel_name
        )
    await self.accept()


async def disconnect(self, close_code):
    await self.channel_layer.group_discard(
            self.user_room_name, 
            self.channel_name
            )


async def user_gossip(self, event):
    await self.send_json(event)
```

When I open the webpage, the websocket connects normally. The problem is when I send a message, and a new notification gets created, I get the following error

```
 "You cannot use AsyncToSync in the same thread as an async event loop - "
 You cannot use AsyncToSync in the same thread as an async event loop - just await the async function directly.
```

After that error, I changed the newNotification in signals.py to async. But then, it never gets called.

Comment: the django signal receiver is just a regular code path in the `save()` process (synchronous). It's exactly the same as adding this code at the end of the `Notification.save()` method. So if you're saving a `Notification` in an async thread, this is not going to work. But due to the `@receiver` construct your code can't know whether this will run inside an event loop or not in advance, so you also can't `await` as suggested in the error. So I think the only way is to move this code to where you generate the `Notification` object and forget about using a signal in this case.

Comment: or maybe look at [async signals](https://github.com/nyergler/async-signals)

Comment: Thanks for explaining! As you suggested, i got it to work by forgetting about signals and moving it to where I generate a notification.